# NULL vs nil in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, null

In `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` - why do the docs use `NULL` instead of `nil` when not specifying a context pointer?

Comment: in my opinion, object is nil, class is Nil, and NULL using for object or class

Answer (score 233, accepted):

`nil` should only be used in place of an `id`, what we Java and C++ programmers would think of as a pointer to an object. Use `NULL` for non-object pointers.

Look at the declaration of that method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Context is a `void *` (ie a C-style pointer), so you'd definitely use `NULL` (which is sometimes declared as `(void *)0`) rather than `nil` (which is of type `id`).

Comment: But since the type of `context` in `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` is `void *`, doesn't that mean that the data passed as the `context` could be an object pointer? I would think that to be a common case. That's why I'm confused as to why the docs always use `NULL` instead of `nil`.

Comment: The type of context: in that method is "void *".  "nil" is not a "void *", but NULL is.

Comment: So is it correct to deduce from this discussion that we *cannot* pass an object pointer (aka, something that can be typed as `nil`) when we pass this message to the object implementing NSKeyValueObserving? Because object pointers cannot be of type `void *` ?

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't know if you can cast an id into a void*.

Comment: You can. void * is any pointer. Nonetheless, you are absolutely right that NULL is the correct constant there.

Comment: This gets to the meat of my question - why is NULL the correct constant in this case, rather than nil? Given that NULL and nil both have the same "value", what I want to understand is the reasons for using one vs the other - is it intended that context not be an object pointer? It seems deliberate.

Comment: They said void *. NULL is for void * and nil is for id. Therefore, you pass NULL. If you pass nil, you are lying to your reader, who will think this method takes an id.

Comment: Peter's got it exactly right - if a function expects a type, and you want to pass a null, pass in the correct null type, not one that just happens to be a subset or have the same internal representation.

Comment: Or to think of it another way, NULL is a broader type, and nil is a subset of NULL.  In general, use the broadest type you can get away with (ie in Java, write your method to expect a Collection instead of a Vector, unless you need something specific from Vector)

Comment: That makes good sense. Thanks to both of you for humoring my persistent questions.

Comment: I'm glad you understand it better now.

Comment: As someone pretty new to the C family of languages, I didn't understand this answer until I also read the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304176/objective-c-difference-between-id-and-void

Perhaps a link to that question would be a helpful addition to this answer? The semantic distinction between 'C-style pointer' and 'pointer to an object' was - to me at least - not obvious from this answer.

Comment: Do you know what is the case when a method receives a pointer to a pointer, i.e.: ...withError: (NSError **)error; ?

Comment: @DanielSanchez Very late answer, but still useful for someone that may have your same question, as I once did. The double-pointer i.e. pointer to a pointer allows the callee to assign the value that NSError points to such that the caller can observe the effects. It's a simple way to return multiple values from a method without writing ugly bundling code.

Answer (score 67):

They're technically the same thing (0), but nil is usually used for an Objective-C object type, while NULL is used for c-style pointers (void *).

Comment: Also, `NULL` is differently defined than `nil`. `nil` is defined as `(id)0`. `NULL` isn't.

Comment: @WTP if you read through MacTypes.h, it declares #define nil NULL

Comment: That is very interesting. It seems it does not matter than other than for style points. It's like YES/TRUE and NO/FALSE.

Comment: @Brennan, That's not entirely true, just because nil is defined as NULL doesn't mean there's some other hidden implementation behind the scenes. For example, IBAction is defined as void but it has a different meaning when using interface builder when displaying methods to attach to actions on buttons and such.

Answer (score 54):

They're technically the same thing and differ only in style:

- Objective-C style says `nil` is what to use for the `id` type (and pointers to objects).
- C style says that `NULL` is what you use for `void *`.
- C++ style typically says that you should just use `0`.

I typically use the variant that matches the language where the type is *declared*.

Answer (score 15):

`NULL` is the **`C equivalent`** of `nil`, a pointer to nothing;

where **`nil is zero typed as id`**,

**`NULL is zero typed as void*`**.

**One important point** you can’t send a message to NULL. So it is preferred to use nil in objective-C at many places.

Answer (score 4):

They almost are the same thing except,

`nil` is used in an Objective-C style.
where `NULL` is for C type pointers and is typdef'ed to `(void *)`.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c/557607#557607)?