# When should I use nil and NULL in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, null, nsnull

This is sample code:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSNumber *myNumber = [myDictionary valueForKey: @"MyNumber"];
NSLog(@"myNumber = %@", myNumber); // output myNumber = (null)

if (myNumber == nil)
    NSLog(@"test 1 myNumber == nil");

if (myNumber == NULL)
    NSLog(@"test 2 myNumber == NULL");

if ([myNumber isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    NSLog(@"test 3 myNumber == [NSNull null]");
```

When should I use nil, NULL and [NSNull null]?

Comment: Its related to Objective C question.

Comment: `nil` means a kind of `NULL` for objc instance. So you can mark specific value is intended for objc instance or generic pointer. In view of type management and safety, this will help you a lot.

Comment: `nil` and `null`/`NULL` are the same -- both defined to be zero.  As a formality, use `nil` when coding Objective-C and `NULL` when coding regular C/C++ statements/calls.  `NSNull` is something entirely different, however.  It's a singleton object that serves as a place-holder to represent "nothing" in, eg, NSDictionarys where nil/null pointers are not allowed.

Comment: Refer link for good explanation [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null

Comment: possible duplicate of [NULL vs nil in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c)

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nil/

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use `nil` about anywhere you can use `null`. The main difference is that you can send messages to `nil`, so you can use it in some places where `null` cant work.

In general, just use `nil`.

Comment: technically, they are exactly equal, you can send messages to both nil and to NULL. Idiomatically though nil is usually used to represent an object

Comment: also, in MacTypes.h there is `#define nil NULL`

Comment: Yeah, as cobbal says, they are the same. It is more a contextual reference where NULL is a pointer to 0x0, nil is a non-existent objective-c object and Nil is a non-existent objective-c class, but technically they are all just 0. Also, it is NULL not null -- null is in Java or C# but not in Objective-C.

Comment: This accepted answer fails to acknowledge that `[NSNull null]` is a very different beast. To quote from [NSNull Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html), "The NSNull class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects (which don’t allow nil values)." Also see [Using NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html) section of _Number and Value Programming Topics._

Comment: "The main difference is that you can send messages to nil" - you can send messages to `NULL` as well.

Comment: I guess that there was a difference historically, but there isn't anymore at this point. This is still a good answer: "In general, just use nil" so I am leaving the up vote.

Comment: Please share example where we can't use NULL.

Comment: This was a main cause of ios facebook issue
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1430
LOL

Answer (score 324):

They differ in their types.  They're all zero, but `NULL` is a `void *`, `nil` is an `id`, and `Nil` is a Class pointer.

Comment: Best explanation I have heard of the difference (: Thanks.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not because there are more up-votes, but because it has the best explanation to the question posed.

Comment: Elegant description of `NULL` v `nil`, but this seriously misses the mark re `[NSNull null]`. See [Using NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html) section of _Number and Value Programming Topics_ and [NSNull Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Both seem to be pointers to `void *`. A different answer here already mentions this, but if you dig into `objc.h`, you'll find the line `#define nill __DARWIN_NULL`.

Comment: This answer sounds good but according to the other answers it's simply incorrect.

Comment: Greg, when did this change?  I remember that NULL, Nil and nil were the same on NextStep.

Answer (score 30):

**nil** is an empty value bound/corresponding with an object (the id type in Objective-C). **nil** got no reference/address, just an empty value.

```
NSString *str = nil;
```

So nil should be used, if we are dealing with an object.

```
if(str==nil)
    NSLog("str is empty");
```

Now **NULL** is used for **non-object pointer** (like a C pointer) in Objective-C. Like **nil** , **NULL** got no value nor address.

```
char *myChar = NULL;
struct MyStruct *dStruct = NULL;
```

So if there is a situation, when I need to check my **struct** (structure type variable) is empty or not then, I will use:

```
if (dStruct == NULL)
    NSLog("The struct is empty");
```

Let’s have another example, the

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Of **key-value observing**, the context should be a C pointer or an object reference. Here for the context we can not use **nil**; we have to use **NULL**.

Finally the **NSNull** class defines a singleton object used to represent null values in collection objects(NSArray, NSDictionary). The **[NSNull null]** will returns the singleton instance of NSNull. Basically **[NSNull null]** is a proper object.

There is no way to insert a nil object into a collection type object. Let's have an example:

```
NSMutableArray *check = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[check addObject:[NSNull null]];
[check addObject:nil];
```

On the second line, we will not get any error, because it is perfectly fair to insert a NSNull object into a collection type object. On the third line, we will get "object cannot be nil" error. Because nil is not an object.

Comment: +1 for mentioning practical use of nil/null in array.

Answer (score 20):

NULL and nil are equal to each other, but nil is an object value while NULL is a generic pointer value (`(void*)0`, to be specific). `[NSNull null]` is an object that's meant to stand in for nil in situations where nil isn't allowed. For example, you can't have a nil value in an NSArray. So if you need to represent a "nil", you can use `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 13):

I've found the following:

objc.h

```
#define Nil __DARWIN_NULL   /* id of Nil class */
#define nil __DARWIN_NULL   /* id of Nil instance */
```

_types.h

```
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
```

stddef.h

```
#undef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#undef __null  // VC++ hack.
#define NULL __null
#else
#define NULL ((void*)0)
#endif
```

MacTypes.h

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL    __DARWIN_NULL
#endif /* ! NULL */
#ifndef nil
    #define nil NULL
#endif /* ! nil */
```

The way it looks, there's no difference but a conceptual one.

Answer (score 8):

Beware that `if([NSNull null])` returns `true`.

Answer (score 7):

They both are just typecast zero's. Functionally, there's no difference between them.
ie.,

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
#define nil ((id)0)
```

There is a difference, but only to yourself and other humans that read the code, the compiler doesn't care.

One more thing nil is an object value while NULL is a generic pointer value.

Answer (score 6):

In modern OS X and iOS SDKs:

- `nil` and `Nil` and `NULL` are identical in Objective-C and in
  Objective-C++ before C++11.
- `nil` and `Nil` and `std::nullptr` are
  identical in Objective-C++ with C++11.

Stylistically, many people prefer to use `nil` for Objective-C objects and `NULL` or `nullptr` for other pointer types. I myself now use `nil` everywhere.

`[NSNull null]` is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object use to represent null values in situations where `nil` is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an `NSArray` or  `NSDictionary`). [Number and Value Programming Topics: Using NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html)

Answer (score 5):

To expand on a comment from @cobbal:

[MacTypes.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacTypes.h) contains:

```
#ifndef nil
   #define nil NULL
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, they are the same, but I use either the one or the other depending on the language in which the corresponding framework was written.

For everything related to Objective-C, I use nil. For example:

```
- (BOOL)doSomethingWithObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)anArray {
    if (anArray == nil) return NO;

    // process elements
    ...
}
```

However, when checking validity of data models from a C-framework (like AddressBook framework and CoreFoundation), I use NULL. For example:

```
- (BOOL)showABUnknownPersonVCForABRecordRef:(ABRecordRef)aRecord {
    if (aRecord == NULL) return NO;

    // set-up the ABUnknownPersonViewController and display it on screen
    ..
}
```

This way, I have subtle clues in my code if I'm dealing with Obj-C or C based code.

Answer (score 4):

**nil** is an object pointer to nothing. 
Although semantically distinct from **NULL**, they are technically **equivalent** to one another.

On the framework level, Foundation defines **NSNull**, which defines a class method, +null, which returns the singleton NSNull object. **NSNull** is different from **nil** or **NULL**, in that it is an **actual** **object**, rather than a zero value.

Additionally, in Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h, **Nil** is defined as a **class** **pointer** to nothing.

[Refer this for further info - nil / Nil / NULL / NSNull](http://nshipster.com/nil/)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference in some contexts.

Literally, Null is a character: ASCII 0.

Nil is equivalent to blank, no value.

Depending on the programming context, this can be a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use NULL for example when you invoke an Objective-C method with an output parameter of type (NSError **).

I see lots of example code on the web where people provide nil instead of NULL in this case. This is because it's a pointer to a pointer and thus not directly an Objective-C object type. As said above, nil should be used for Objective-C object types.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:
nil: null pointer on an object and 
null: is for other type pointer

Answer (score 0):

nil means absence of value while NULL represent No Object,

NSArray *array = @[@"Hello World !", @101,[NSNULL null] ];

Here [NSNULL null] is an object which means no object, at the same time you cannot add nil to indicate absence of object.

you can use both nil and [NSNUll null] for checking too.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to understand the difference between nil, NIL and null.

The below link may help you in some way:

http://nshipster.com/nil/

> nil -> literal null value for Objective-C objects.
>
> Nil -> literal null value for Objective-C classes.
>
> NULL -> literal null value for C pointers.
>
> NSNULL -> singleton object used to represent null.

Comment: does this add anything new (which isn't covered by the existing answers)?