# Are NULL and nil equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, null, nsnull

Actually my question here is: are `null` and `nil` equivalent or not?

I have an example but I am confused when they are equal when they are not.

```
NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null];
NSArray *arrayWithNull = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nullValue];
NSLog(@"arrayWithNull: %@", arrayWithNull);
id aValue = [arrayWithNull objectAtIndex:0];

if (aValue == nil) {
    NSLog(@"equals nil");
} else if (aValue == [NSNull null]) {
    NSLog(@"equals NSNull instance");
    if ([aValue isEqual:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"isEqual:nil");
    }
}
```

Here in the above case it shows that both `null` and `nil` are not equal and it displays "equals NSNull instance"

```
NSString *str=NULL;
id str1=nil;
if(str1 == str)
{
   printf("\n IS EQUAL........");

}
else
{
    printf("\n NOT EQUAL........");
}
```

And in the second case it shows both are equal and it displays "IS EQUAL".

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: The code here bears a striking resemblance to this article:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use nil and NULL in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nil` and `NULL` are essentially the same, `nil` is something like `(NSObject *)0`, while `NULL` is more like `(void *)0`. But both are pointers with an integer value of zero. You can send messages to `nil` without raising an error.

`NSNull` and `NULL` (or `nil`, of course) are different things, however. You just use `NSNull` as a helper to add an `empty` object to an `NSArray` or another container class, since you can't add `nil` to them. So instead, you use `[NSNull null]` as a replacement, and you have to check if an array element is `NSNull`, not if it's `nil` (it will never be equal to `nil`).

Comment: Apparently according to the Apple Docs NSNull is Not (NSObject *)0 but is a valid instance.

Comment: Does that mean that (str1==str) is using an operator-overload for == which is a value comparison instead of an identity comparison?  That might be the source of confusion leading to the original question.

Comment: Indeed, `NSNull` is a valid object. That's what I wanted to say. There is no operator overloading in Objective C, by the way. Comparisons of Objective C objects are just pointer comparisons.

Comment: @Warren P: FWIW, you can use == to compare to `[NSNull null]` only because it's guaranteed to always return the same object instance.

Answer (score 7):

From http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/34826-nil-vs-null.html

**`nil` and `NULL` are 100% interchangeable.**

From:

- `NULL` is for C-style memory pointers.
- `nil` is for Objective-C objects.
- `Nil` is for Objective-C classes.

Whenever you're writing Objective-C code, use `nil`
Whenever you're writing C code, use `NULL`

But ultimately they're all defined as the same thing -- (void *)0, I think -- so in practice it doesn't really matter.

Comment: NSNull is not the same as NULL.

Comment: You're right. [NSNull null] is a singleton value used to represent a nil value in a situation which prohibits the use of nil -- for example in a collection class (like NSDictionary, NSArray, NSSet, or mutable variants).

Comment: In other words, it's used as a placeholder in collections which do not allow you to set an item to nil.

Comment: Can I use nil in C code in a Objective-C implementation file. Since you can combine them, can I combine nil and NULL? Just to be sure. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The concept is the same, with the difference that it's valid to send messages (call method) to nil.

NSNull is a real (singleton) class, that can be used for arrays or dictionnaries, who don't accept NULL or nil values.

Answer (score 2):

Biggest difference between them: sending a message to an `NSNULL` object is probably going to cause a crash, whereas it's cool to send any message to `nil`. For example, if you use a key path to get an array, like so:

```
NSArray *departmentNames = [departments valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Then you will have an `NSNULL` object for any department whose `name` is `nil`. So, this is going to cause a crash:

```
for (NSString *name in departmentNames)
    NSLog(@"%@", [name lowercaseString]);
```

whenever `name` is `NSNull`, because you just sent an unknown selector (`lowercaseString`) to an `NSNull`.

Lesson: check for the `NSNull` object in an array before sending any message to its elements.

```
for (NSString *name in departmentNames)
    if (name != [NSNull null])
         NSLog(@"%@", [name lowercaseString]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `NSNull` and `nil` are not the same. They both represent a lack of value, and you might want to treat them the same, but they are still not equal.

The `NSNull` object instance represents a null value, for example when you read data from a database that has null values.

The `nil` value is a null pointer, i.e. it doesn't point to any object instance.

In your second code you don't have any `NSNull` instance. An `NSString` pointer that contains a null pointer is not an `NSNull` instance, it's still just a null pointer. You are comparing one null pointer to another, and they are of course equal.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you typecast [NSNull null] to object type that you are comparing

```
NSArray list;
if(list==(NSArray *)[NSNull null])
    // do something
```

otherwise you will receive a warning message saying "Comparison of distinct pointer types('type *' and 'NSNull *')