# Do I need to release an NSString created by CFUUIDCreateString()?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsstring, core-foundation

I am creating a NSString like this, should I release it afterwards or not?

```
CFUUIDRef   uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
        NSString *device = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
        CFRelease(uuidObj);
```

Thanks!

Comment: hmm.. the convention is that when you do alloc or have *Alloc* in your method, you need to release them.

Comment: I am allocing it here correct? I don't see the word alloc anywhere but I am assuming I am allocing it right?

Comment: if no "alloc" in the method, you didn't alloc then. you don't have to call release on those objects.

EDIT: in addition to alloc, there are new, copy, mutableCopy. I am including the Apple Memory Management Guide as Answer.

Comment: Kenny, this is an Core Foundation function falling under the Core Foundation memory guidelines which says that the keyword "create" in fact does delegate the ownership back to the caller!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is documentation for this function:

[CFUUID Reference - CFUUIDCreateString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreateString)

and it states that ownership follows **[The Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)**.

Here are some more links with answer:

- [Memory management with CF Objects](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/6405-memory-management-with-cf-objects.html)
- [Strings from UUID](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/60751-strings-from-uuid.html)

Comment: Thanks for all the info and help!
So your saying this code: device = [(NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, CFUUIDCreate(NULL)) autorelease];

Will do the same as my code in my original post?

Comment: The comment to use NULL instead of 0 was to the original poster on the first link, not to you. :) Here are some links for the NULL and nil differences. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461617/are-null-and-nil-equivalent

Answer (score 6):

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);

NSString *s2ndUuid = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID);
```