# Difference between nil, NIL, and null in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, null, nsnull

I want to know the difference between `nil`, `NIL`, and `null`.
I've googled around and found this:

`nil` -> null pointer to Objective-C object

`NIL` -> null pointer to Objective-C class

`null` -> null pointer to primitive type or absence of data

But I'm not able to understand the terms "Objective-C object" and "class" clearly.

Please explain this to me. Also, is there any word like `NSNull` or `NSNil` in Objective-C? If so, then please explain for what it is for.

Comment: An Objective-C object is an instance of an Objective-C class (the one which is declared via @interface). The instance is usuallay created with [[MyClass alloc] init] or [MyClass new].

Comment: In ObjC difference between object and class is the same as in any other language. If you don't know that - you should learn the OOP basics.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

`nil` is the literal null value for Objective-C objects, corresponding to the abstract type `id` or any Objective-C type declared via `@interface`. For instance:

```
NSString *someString = nil;
NSURL *someURL = nil;
id someObject = nil;

if (anotherObject == nil) // do something
```

`Nil` is the literal null value for Objective-C classes, corresponding to the type `Class`. Since most code doesn’t need variables to reference classes, its use is not common. One example is:

```
Class someClass = Nil;
Class anotherClass = [NSString class];
```

`NULL` is the literal null value for arbitrary C pointers. For instance,

```
int *pointerToInt = NULL;
char *pointerToChar = NULL;
struct TreeNode *rootNode = NULL;
```

`NSNull` is a class for objects that represent null. In fact, there’s only one object, namely the one returned by `+[NSNull null]`. It is different from `nil` because `nil` is a literal null value, i.e., it isn’t an object. The single instance of `NSNull`, on the other hand, is a proper object.

`NSNull` is often used in Foundation collections since they cannot store `nil` values. In the case of dictionaries, `-objectForKey:` returns `nil` to indicate that a given key has no corresponding object in the dictionary, i.e., the key hasn’t been added to the dictionary. If you want to make it explicit that you have a certain key but it doesn’t have a value yet, you can use `[NSNull null]`.

For instance, the following throws an exception because dictionaries cannot store `nil` values:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:nil forKey:@"someKey"];
```

On the other hand, the following code is valid since `[NSNull null]` is a non-`nil` object:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"someKey"];
```

It’s worth mentioning that Foundation collections have initialisers that use `nil` as a marker for the end of a list of objects without having to specify the number of elements in the list. This can only happen because `nil` cannot be stored in a Foundation collection. For instance,

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", nil];
```

As for `NIL` or `NSNil`, there are no such things in Objective-C or Apple Foundation.

Comment: You should also note that it is possible to send messages to `nil` without getting segmentation faults.

Comment: nice explaination thanks. but i would like to ask that can we use NULL for objective C objects?? like--->   id mYobj = NULL ??

Comment: This can be reflected to swift? Like, is in swift a correspondence for that?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure but i think `nil` should only be used in place of an `id`, what Java and C++ programmers would think of as a `pointer` to an `object`. Use `NULL` for non-object pointers.

`nil` is usually used for an Objective-C object type, while `NULL` is used for c-style pointers

Comment: This is correct. I think in practice it doesn't really matter which you use. But follow the convention.

Comment: The convention is useful but it's good to know that nil and NULL and Nil are all the same to the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

**Nil,Null and nil are used with below**

1> Nil for Objective c Class

2> nil for Objective c object

3> Null for C pointer

**Example:**

1>Class A=Nil;

2>NSString strName=nil;

3>char *pointerChar = NULL;

Comment: elegant example buddy

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a class `MyClass`
then by convention `nil` is used if you want to initialize its instance to null value (same as `null` in java)
i.e.

```
MyClass *obj = nil;
```

and if you want to initialize a primitive pointer to null value (same as in c) you use

```
int *ptr = NULL;
```

and if you want to initialize to `Class` reference to null value (same as `null` in java) then use

```
Class classRefOfMyClass = Nil;
```

It's just a convention otherwise Nil or nil have same meaning and perhaps NULL , nil or Nil all are same.

Here is the definition for these in `objc.h` file

```
#ifndef Nil
# if __has_feature(cxx_nullptr)
#   define Nil nullptr
# else
#   define Nil __DARWIN_NULL
# endif
#endif

#ifndef nil
# if __has_feature(cxx_nullptr)
#   define nil nullptr
# else
#   define nil __DARWIN_NULL
# endif
#endif
```

And in `stddef.h`

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

And the definition of `__DARWIN_NULL` in `_types.h`

```
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
```

So there is no difference logically. The main idea here is to initialize a pointer whether `C` or `Objective-C` to `0`. If you have knowledge of `C` then you can assign

```
int *ptr = 0;
```

without type casting `0` to a pointer. As you don't need to typecast `0` to assign it to a pointer.

## In short they all are `0` and nothing else.

Comment: Java's `NULL` is in lower-case: `null`

Answer (score 5):

This will help you to understand the difference between nil,NIL and null.

> All three of these values represent null, or zero pointer, values. The
>   difference is that while **NULL** represents **zero for any pointer,** **nil** is
>   specific to **objects** (e.g., id) and **Nil** is specific to **class pointers.**
>   It should be considered a best practice of sorts to use the right null
>   object in the right circumstance for documentation purposes, even
>   though there is nothing stopping someone from mixing and matching as
>   they go along.

The below link may help you in some way:

http://nshipster.com/nil/

Here is some important part from the link:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

nil, NIL and null. is depended on your requirement.

**NSNull**

collections like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` not being able to contain nil values.

```
NSMutableDictionary *MymutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
MymutableDictionary[@"someKey"] = [NSNull null]; // Sets value of NSNull singleton for "someKey"
NSLog(@"Keys: %@", [mutableDictionary allKeys]);
```

**nil**

all pointers that object has to other objects begin as nil, so it's unnecessary to, for instance, set self.(association) = nil in init methods.

In other languages, like C++, this would crash your program, but in Objective-C, invoking a method on nil returns a zero value.

```
if (name != nil)
{
........
}
```

### **Symbol   Value       Meaning**

nil         (id)0         literal null value for Objective-C objects

Nil        (Class)0       literal null value for Objective-C classes