# Undeclared Identifier - Xcode 4

Tags: ios, objective-c

This seems to be a recurring theme...I have only one error and it is an undeclared identifier at the line...`addBadgeToView:AppButton` in the app_delegate with `AppButton` being the culprit. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

app_header:

```
-(void) addBadgeToView:(UIView *)badgeView badgeText:(NSString *)badgeText badgeLocation:(CGPoint)badgeLocation shouldFlashBadge:(BOOL)shouldFlashBadge;
```

app_delegate:

```
-(void) AppNeedsToUpdateBadge:(int)badgeNum hasNumberChanged:(BOOL)hasNumberChanged

{

    NSString *badgeText = NULL;
    if(badgeNum > 0)
    {
        badgeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", badgeNum];

    }


    [[AppManager sharedManager] addBadgeToView:AppButton badgeText:badgeText badgeLocation:CGPointMake(0,0) shouldFlashBadge:hasNumberChanged];


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNum;
}
```

Comment: try setting *badgeText to nil, instead of NULL.

Comment: In support of @MiRAGe's comment, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously haven't declared `AppButton`. Maybe it's named `appButton`? The capital A indicates that it's a class. What you want is a `UIView` object.