# What are the differences between nil, NULL and [NSNULL nil]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, null, invalidargumentexception

I got an error like this -

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:  **-[NSCFDictionary
> initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil value at
> objects[0] (key: searched)'**

Then I tried the below code

```
if (Obj == (id)[NSNull null])  //Obj is an id 
{
    NSLog(@" Obj is (id)[NSNull null]");    
}
else if (Obj == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Obj is nil");   
} 
else if (Obj == NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Obj is NULL");  
} 
else
{
    NSLog(@"Obj is something else");
}

searchedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:Obj forKey:@"searched"];
```

And I got the NSLog message as 'Obj is nil'.

But when I used the same above code when Obj was NSString and my app got terminated due to nil value, I got  the NSLog message as 'Obj is (id)[NSNull null]'.

**What are the differences between nil, NULL and [NSNULL nil] ?**

**Are there different kinds of Null values? if yes, How to check commonly for these null values**?

Thanks :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone+Difference between nil,NIL and null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908936/iphonedifference-between-nil-nil-and-null)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`NULL` is the original C-style value given to a pointer which is deemed to point to no explicit address. It's generally just used to mean "unset" or as a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

```
char * oldstring = NULL;
```

`nil` is the Objective-C version of the same thing as applied to Obj-C object references:

```
NSString * str = nil;
id foo = nil;
```

They are both defined to be equal to the value zero, and although you *could* use them interchangeably, the former is seen mainly within Obj-C for traditional pointers (like setting `void *` context pointers to NULL) and `nil` is used for all Obj-C object references.

The difference exists because although Obj-C's syntax happens to ride on top of C's, the design of the language is higher-level, and its object IDs [aren't conceptually the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189212/why-object-dosomething-and-not-object-dosomething/2214601#2214601) as just "pointers". Hence the creation of a special sentinel for them.

`[NSNull null]` is an object [that is intended](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to be uses in very certain cases (like inserting into collections) where an "non-value" value is desired, but actual `nil` is not allowed, and an object must be used.

Note that `nil` and `NSNull` stringify very similarly: `nil` stringifies as `(null)`, and `NSNull` as `<null>`.

Answer (score 5):

`[NSNull null]` is a wrapper for the `nil` value you want to insert in the collection, if it is what you want.

[NSNull](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

You can also check before if an object reference is `nil` simply with `==`.

Also `nil` is defined as : `#define nil NULL` and is Objective C equivalent for C `NULL`.

Comment: Thanx for quick response :) okay, I checked the 'NSNull class reference'. Are nil and NULL different?

Comment: @S.Philip - no `nil` is just another way to say `NULL` according to its definition

Comment: @S.Philip - you are welcome. you can find useful informations like in Apple's [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163).

Answer (score 1):

Nil is for object pointers

NULL is for non pointers

[NSNULL null] is an object to represent "nil" to be used in cases that nil values are not allowed (as pointed out by Vince, like in collections e.g. NSArray and NSDictionary)