# some confusions about [NSNull null]，nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between [NSNull null] and nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836601/whats-the-difference-between-nsnull-null-and-nil)
>   [What are the differences between nil, NULL and [NSNULL nil]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814427/what-are-the-differences-between-nil-null-and-nsnull-nil)

1.

```
id dicValue = [aDictionary objetForKey:@"aKey"];

if(dicValue != nil)
{
     blablala...
}
```

or

2.

```
if(dicValue != [NSNull null]) 
{
     blablala...
}
```

should I choose the first one,or the second one?

or when it comes like this :

3.

```
if ([aDictionary objetForKey:@"aKey"] != nil)
```

or

4.

```
if ([aDictionary objetForKey:@"aKey"] != [NSNull null])
```

and what again ?

1.2.3.4. which is correct and recommended?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Directly from [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html).
The NSNull class defines a singleton object you use to represent null values in situations where nil is prohibited as a value (typically in a collection object such as an array or a dictionary).

```
NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null];
NSArray *arrayWithNull = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nullValue];
NSLog(@"arrayWithNull: %@", arrayWithNull);
// output: "arrayWithNull: (<null>)"
```

It is important to appreciate that the NSNull instance is semantically different from NO or false—these both represent a logical value; the NSNull instance represents the absence of a value. The NSNull instance is semantically equivalent to nil, however it is also important to appreciate that it is not equal to nil. To test for a null object value, you must therefore make a direct object comparison.

```
id aValue = [arrayWithNull objectAtIndex:0];
if (aValue == nil) {
    NSLog(@"equals nil");
} else if (aValue == [NSNull null]) {
    NSLog(@"equals NSNull instance");
    if ([aValue isEqual:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"isEqual:nil");
    }
}
// output: "equals NSNull instance"
```

Is it clear now??

Comment: this helped so much thank you! was looking for comparison operators all over SO

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that NSNull is an object representing a NULL value and nil is just an empty pointer.

You can fill a NSArray with NSNull objects and it'll return null values, but you can't fill it with nils.

You can do

```
[myNsMutableArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
```

but this would crash:

```
[myNsMutableArray addObject:nil];
```

Likewise:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", nil, @"2", nil];  
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", [NSNull null], @"2", nil];
```

The first array, when printed would output "1"
The second one would output: "1, null, 2"

So you can use NSNull to represent empty spaces in an array.

You can't insert nil into a dictionary. So checking for it means the key doesn't exist. If you check for NSNull it means that the key exists but holds an empty (NSNull) value.

Answer (score 1):

First one means there is no such key, second means that key's value is `NSNull`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use the first one; or rather, a slight variation:

```
if (dicValue) {
  // blablabla...
}
```

`NSNull` is for use when you need a valid object, for example for use as a dictionary key, array entry, or similar.

`nil` is equal to `(id)NULL`; it is generally taken to mean "No value".

`[NSNull null]`, on the other hand, is an object holding an empty value; taken to mean "A value of None".

Very few methods return an `NSNull` value, and it is generally only encountered if you introduce it yourself.

It exists mostly because `nil` cannot be inserted into arrays; and works as an empty marker for arrays that require it.

---

On a related note; the "`!= nil`" part of your expression is redundant; any valid pointer to an object evaluates to true in a boolean expression, and nil evaluates to false.

Comment: 3q,i know it is redundant,but i still like to add the "!= nil" part.it makes the code easy to read !do you think so:)