# Passing empty Array to AFNetworking request's parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking` to create request with `NSDictionary *parameters`. One of my key value pairs are empty arrays:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray new];
```

When I had created such example of parameters:

```
parameters = @{"ids": array, "name": "someName"};
```

Server received:

```
parameters = @{"name": "someName"};
```

Why the keys with empty arrays were removed?

After a long digging it turned out that the problem is with `NSMutableArray`'s method.

`AFNetworking` uses at some moment `NSMutableArray`'s method `addObjectsFromArray:`. It is not mentioned in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:), but this method adds nothing if array is empty.

When I replace my empty array with `NSNull()` or array with one element `NSNull()` the server do not receive it at all.

Anyone know how is it happening, or how to solve that problem?

Comment: replace the array with *[array count] >0 ? array:[NSNull null]*, this will add a null object to your dictionary. make sure to handle it at backend.

Comment: but `NSNull()` is still removed... what can be instead of it?

Comment: I think you should confirm to your server guy first that what he/she is willing to accept as null object or blank value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue earlier in which I had to send an empty array to the server. This is what I had to do in order for the server to accept my request:

```
NSNull *nullValue = [NSNull null];
NSArray *arrayWithNull = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nullValue];
[payload setObject:arrayWithNull forKey:@"ids"];
```

In my case, the server returns this response:

```
ids =     (
    ""
);
```

The code used here I found in another SO question, found here:
[some confusions about [NSNull null]，nil [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121293/some-confusions-about-nsnull-null-nil)

Comment: Can you check what information is being sent to the server? You can normally do this in the debugger, by grabbing the HTTPBody from NSMutableURLRequest:

po [[NSString alloc] initWithData:request.HTTPBody encoding:4]

Just make sure that within the payload being sent to the server, that you have a URL parameter called ids[]

Answer (score 0):

you can try with assign capacity to NSArray while you allocating memory to it

```
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
```

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to be a problem with the way AFNetworking handles things. I have made a fix for this within the AFNetworking library and have opened a pull request here:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/642158bac875362314c7db18a73d5a0e2137fd98

I hope it gets approved but in the meantime feel free to use my implementation by modifying your own fork of AFNetworking.