# What's the difference between (null) vs <null>?

Tags: objective-c, crash, nsstring, null

I was getting random crashes in my app until I narrowed it down to a particular method. In that method I expect an `NSString` as a parameter. This `NSString` can sometimes be nil in which case the method ends and no harm is done.

When I run my method's parameter through `NSLog(@"%@", myString)` I found that I get one of these:

1. The contents of an actual NSString
2. (null)
3. <null>

The first two are expected and handled by my method. The third one, *<null>*, crashes my app with `-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b2ace8`.

I have found a way around the problem by checking for `nil` or `isKindOfClass`, but my question is **what is the difference between (null) and <null>?**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between nil, NULL and \[NSNULL nil\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814427/what-are-the-differences-between-nil-null-and-nsnull-nil)

Comment: @duskwuff: Note that neither the question nor the answers there address the two description strings, `(null)` and `<null>`.

Comment: I've edited the accepted answer to include a note on how the two values stringify. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(null)` is the string that `NSLog()` prints when you use the format specifier `%@` with a `nil` value. `<null>` is the result of sending `description` to the `NSNull` singleton (which you access via `[NSNull null]`).

`NSNull` is used as a "no object" placeholder in Cocoa collections (`NSArray` and `NSDictionary`) because they cannot contain `nil`.

The two description strings are confusingly similar, and one could argue that `NSNull` should have a bug filed against it to make this a little more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clearing that up! I have to hunt the origin of that NSNull in my app then. For the life of me I've been trying for the last few hours to no avail.

Comment: Parsing JSON seems to be the most common task that causes this issue -- constructing a Cocoa collection with some missing data requires the use of `NSNull`.

Comment: And you are right one more time. I've found the culprit inside a dictionary coming from a remote JSON object. Thanks!