# (null) and <null>, what differences between?

Tags: objective-c, ios

When i try to display the value of a Dictionary value:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.user valueForKeyPath:@"age"]);
```

The first time, i got `(null)`, the second time i got `<null>`

What differences does exist between the two result? Thanx in advance.

Comment: You should use `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:` (or even worse, `valueForKeyPath:`) to access dictionary contents! The first one is the designated accessor while the other two are actually used for KVC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between (null) vs <null>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287590/whats-the-difference-between-null-vs-null)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `NSLog` outputs `(null)`, it means that it was literally passed in `0x0`, or `NULL`.

When it outputs `<null>`, it means that it was passed in `[NSNull null]`, instead.

`NSNull`'s are commonly used in arrays & other collections that cannot store `nil` by default. Thus, a special object is used instead.