# Why does this null check fail?

Tags: objective-c, nsnull

I am using this simple code to check if an NSString object is null, but for some reason it fails

here is my simple check

```
NSString *imageUrl = [dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"];

    NSLog(@"Jonge: %@", imageUrl);

    if(![imageUrl isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        NSLog(@"In the loop");
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageUrl];
        NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
```

The debug clearly shows the object is null as follows

```
2017-10-23 11:48:22.711228+0800 NWMobileTill[46614:7498779] Jonge: (null)
```

But I still end up in the loop as below

```
2017-10-23 11:48:22.711367+0800 NWMobileTill[46614:7498779] In the loop
```

Why is my null check not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between \[NSNull null\] and nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836601/whats-the-difference-between-nsnull-null-and-nil)

Comment: Closely related: [What's the difference between (null) vs <null>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11287590)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(null)` represents `nil`, not `[NSNull null]`, so the check `imageUrl != NSNull` succeeds.

You have to write

```
if (imageUrl) {
```

which is the same as

```
if (imageUrl != nil) {
```

Comment: Is there a document about the different types null nil etc? I googled but could not find a good one

Comment: `NSNull` is used only in a few cases. Mattt Thompson wrote an [article about `nil / Nil / NULL / NSNull`](http://nshipster.com/nil/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check for string is blank or not.

```
if(![imageUrl isEqualToString:@""])
```

Or

```
if(![imageUrl isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`nil` represents nothing or in technical term, we can say that `'\0'` (according to C concepts). When ever we make an instance of any Class, by default Objective C makes it nil.

`[NSNull null]` will give an Object. In Objective C, use of `NSNull` is limited. It is used in collections (like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`)

As you are using a NSDictionary, you can check it as below.

```
if ([dict objectForKey:@"imageUrl"] != [NSNull null]) {
    //your code...
}
```