# Null or Nil to return from method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a method and I want to return an object or lack of object if the method cannot find what it needs to. What's the best practice to return a lack of object, should it be `[NSNull null]` or `nil`? or it doesn't make any difference?

Comment: See this NSHipster article on the differences between nil, Nil, NULL, and NSNull: http://nshipster.com/nil/

Comment: Also worth reading the NSNull Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNull_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814427/what-are-the-differences-between-nil-null-and-nsnull-nil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The convention is to return `nil` for Objective-C pointers (e.g. where the type is `id`, `NSSomething *`, `UISomething *`, etc.), `NULL` for arbitrary C pointers (e.g. `int*`, `struct MyStruct*`, `void (*)(int)`.

`[NSNull null]` is only useful when you want to put a null value into an `NS` collection like `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. So, `[NSNull null]` is a singleton Objective-C object that represents the null value (or the absence of value) by convention, there's nothing special about it otherwise.

Comment: Just one hint, pay attention that if you put Nil in a collection you create an exception and the app will crash, so it really depends on the purpose of the method.

Comment: Which is the reason you test for nil before adding the returned object to a collection and is a standard idiom.