# Requesting NSSharingServices outputs "Could not instantiate class NSURL"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

The main File menu for my app has a *Share* menu, with standard sharing services requested normally through `[NSSharingServices sharingServicesForItems:@[self.fileURL]]`. It is never called when `fileURL` is null.

However, this requests outputs the following error:

```
Could not instantiate class NSURL. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 
   "value for key 'root' was of unexpected class 'NSNull'. Allowed classes are '{( NSURL )}'."
```

The only value contained in the array is `self.fileURL`, which is of class `NSURL`. The sharing menu itself works with no problem, and the only problem is this strange error in the console. What am I doing wrong and where might this null value come from?

Comment: Where does `self.fileURL` come from?

Comment: See [What are the differences between nil, NULL and \[NSNULL nil\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814427/what-are-the-differences-between-nil-null-and-nsnull-nil)

Comment: It's a standard document-based app, with `fileURL` pointing to the document location: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocument/1515038-fileurl?language=objc

Comment: @Tritonal I have the same problem and I'm not sure if it's related but the share dialog also doesn't immediately appear over the document or appears half-transparent. Not sure if these two things are related. Do you also see this? Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I created a couple of document-based apps from the scratch for testing purposes and had the same behavior, so I'm guessing it's either a bug or an undocumented feature.