# Exception datasource must return a cell in tableView with customCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    if (tableView ==tableview1) {
        ContactCustom *cell1=(ContactCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell1 == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCustom" owner:self options:nil];
            cell1 = contactCustom;
        }



        NSString *nameStr = [newcontactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray * arr = [nameStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];
        NSLog(@"arr %@\n",arr);

        [cell1 ContactNameText:[arr objectAtIndex:0]];
        [cell1 MobileNoText:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];

        if (![[arr objectAtIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"no"]) {
           [cell1 ScreenNameText:[arr objectAtIndex:3]]; 
        }

        if (![[arr objectAtIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [cell1 setImg:[arr objectAtIndex:4]];
        }
        else
        {
            cell1.receiveCountBtn.hidden=YES;
        }

        cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell1.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell1;
    }

    else if (tableView ==tableview2) {

        ContactPicsCustom *cell=(ContactPicsCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactPicsCustom" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = contactPicsCustom;
        }

        NSString *nameStr = [sentPicsContactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSArray * arr1 = [nameStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];
//        NSLog(@"arr1 %@\n",arr1);

        User *userObj = [[User alloc]init];
        userObj.fName = [arr1 objectAtIndex:0];
        userObj.mNo = [arr1 objectAtIndex:1];

//        NSLog(@"user %@ %@\n",userObj.fName,userObj.mNo);

        [cell ContactNameText:[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]];

        if ([arr1 count] == 4) {
            [cell ScreenNameText:[arr1 objectAtIndex:3]];
        }

//        [cell setImg:[dicPhotosCount valueForKey:[arr1 objectAtIndex:0]]];
        NSInteger cnt = [[DBModel database]photosCnt:userObj];
//        NSLog(@"cnt: %d\n",cnt);
        if(cnt >= 1)
        {
            [cell setImg:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cnt]];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imgView.hidden=YES;
        }

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        return cell;
    }

        return 0;
}
```

I have added `tabBarController` in my project.There is one `tabBarItem` called `ContactsViewController` which has tableView with customCell.When I click on the tableViewRow it takes me to next view.then I click someother tabBarItem and again click `ContactsViewController` i am getting error as `UITableView` dataSource must return a cell from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.What is wrong with my code?

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {

    }
    else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {

 UINavigationController *requiredNavigationController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
        [requiredNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

after i added above method in Appdelegate.m i am getting excepion

Comment: your `return 0;` code is causing this issue..

Comment: though i removed it i am getting same error

Comment: jsut add return nil; instead return 0;

Comment: @sugan.s Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5909287/468724) and it will clear that using `0` is absolutely fine.

Comment: still having same error

Comment: why you kept return 0; at last?

Comment: no @Sunny it will not create any issue.

Comment: getting warning control may reach end of function

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
 return 0;
```

To :

```
 return nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Table is not getting your custom cell.Check your ContactCustom cell.xib and add your ContactCustom as the class of the cell.
[image]

add your custom class name instead of "DeckListCell".

try this:

```
if (tableView ==tableview1) {
            ContactCustom *cell1=(ContactCustom *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
    { 
       NSArray *nib;
       nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ContactCustom" owner:self  options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[ContactCustom class]])
                cell = (ContactCustom *)oneObject;

       // configure your cell.
    }
  return cell;
 }
```

Comment: no.still it gives same error.i edited my code above.did u see it?

Comment: will you please debug and check on which table it is happen? table1 or table2

Comment: In contactsViewController i display list of contacts.When user selects particular contact it takes to the next view where list of images for that contact.If no images are there i am getting exception.It is with table1