# Retrieving values from NSUserDefault - error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to retrieve a value from a `NSUserDefaults`. When I retrieve the value I get a `(null)`, which is fine.

How can I validate it ?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Value"] !=[NSNull null] ) {
   NSlog(@"returns a value");
} else NSlog(@"return a null");
```

However, even though I get a `null` it doesn't get detected (It goes in to the `if` block). How can i sort this?

Comment: `NSNull`, or `[NSNull null]` is a class reference. So checking `!= [NSNull null]` would be checking it against the class `NSNull`.

Comment: Related/Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5909310/2535467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if ([defaults objectForKey:@"Value"] != nil) {
     NSlog(@"returns a value");
 } else {
    NSlog(@"return a nil");
 }
```

This will work. And what Eiko said is right.

Comment: It says: `use of undeclared identifier 'null'`

Comment: Because it is nil...Not null.

Comment: My apologies, I made a mistake

Answer (score 2):

`nil` is not the same as `[NSNull null]`. Just check with `value != nil`.

`nil` is (simplified) 0. `[NSNull null]` is a real object.

Comment: Sorry, meant nil. I've done to much c++ lately with nullptr. :)