# Get file size given a path

Tags: objective-c, macos, path, filesize

I'm new in objective-c.
I have a path to file contained in an NSString and I want get file size. I found this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileAttributesAtPath%3atraverseLink%3a) and change deprecated code with attributesOfItemAtPath:error: but path is always invalid.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *path = @"~/Library/Safari/History.plist";
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath: path error: NULL];


if (fileAttributes != nil) {
    NSNumber *fileSize;

    if (fileSize == [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]) {
        NSLog(@"File size: %qi\n", [fileSize unsignedLongLongValue]);
    }

}
else {
    NSLog(@"Path (%@) is invalid.", pPath);
}
[NSFileManager release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
uint64_t fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:_filePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

It's very similar to the one used by you, but in yours there's a mistake: you put `NULL` instead of `nil` in the `error:` handling.

Make sure also to expand tilde in your path, as explained in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html): use `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`, so your `NSString *path` should be something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSString stringWithString:@"~/Library/Safari/History.plist"] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c) you can find some explanations about the difference between `nil` and `NULL`.

Comment: I think the problem is not tilde (~), with  NSString *path = @"Whatever.txt"; the code don't work.

Comment: Have you tried with `nil` instead of `NULL` in error handling? The code I've posted is tested and used in some of my applications, so I'm sure it works. Try with the **full path**, e.g. **/Users/USERNAME/Library/Safari/History.plist** and use the `defaultMangaer` of `NSFileManager ` instead creating your own instance. [Here (http://pastebin.com/XBBCvqGu)](http://pastebin.com/XBBCvqGu) I wrote a piece of code that does what you're looking for: it's tested and it works.

Comment: I tried nil and there isn't error but the code don't work. In console I tried your code and it's ok, but can I need to enter your user name. how can I not put it? only /Library/Safari/History.plist?

Comment: [Here (http://pastebin.com/DCMWwnXK)](http://pastebin.com/DCMWwnXK) you find the code without needing to put the username.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to expand the path using:

```
 - (NSString *)stringByExpandingTildeInPath
```

Comment: This method is under-rated. I love it :) Much simpler and more readable than stringWithFormat and NSHomeDirectory().

Answer (score 1):

you can get size by :

```
NSDictionary * properties = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:yourFilePath error:nil];
NSNumber * size = [properties objectForKey: NSFileSize];
```

size is a NSNumber that contains a unsigned long long.

Answer (score 1):

Your Path will always be invalid because of a super-silly bug in your code.

Change

```
if (fileSize == [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]) {
```

to

```
if (fileSize = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]) {
```

I hope no further explanatiuon would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `defaultManager` class method on NSFileManager  instead of creating your own instance. Also, do not include `~` (tilde) symbol in your file path. Use the `NSHomeDirectory()` function to get the home directory instead. Here's an example:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Safari/History.plist", NSHomeDirectory()];
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] fileSize];
```

This should return the size of your file.

Comment: without NSDictionary *fileAttributes the rest of the code does not work. Ok without ~ using for example NSString *path = @"Whatever.txt";
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath: path error: NULL];  the code don't work again.