# Difference between Nil and nil and Null in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, null

I am a relatively experienced iOS developer, however one thing has always bothered me, what is the difference between Nil(Capital) and nil(lowercase) and NULL (if any) in terms of performance and usage? I am absolutely sure that there is a difference between them otherwise why would they be defined as separately in the first place...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1564846/1404239

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic idea is that you use NULL for C pointers (0 for C primitives), nil for Objective C instances, Nil for Objective C classes, and [NSNull](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html) as a way of pretending that nothing is something so that you can store an instance of nothing in an array or dictionary.

A great description of this and the source of the values listed below can be found at: http://nshipster.com/nil/

> NULL  (void *)0   literal null value for C pointers
>
> nil   (id)0   literal null value for Objective-C objects
>
> Nil   (Class)0    literal null value for Objective-C classes
>
> NSNull    [NSNull null]   singleton object used to represent null