# How to detect if a SKLabelNode is valued (Null)

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

In order to compare the string of 2 nodes, the text input is

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString: otherNode.name]) {
}
```

I am trying to find something like that except instead of comparing it, I want to find out if the string has a value of NULL.

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:NULL]){
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The method `isEqualToString:` is used to compare the text values contained in two `NSString` objects. It may be used to check whether the string is empty.

```
[node.name isEqualToString:@""];
```

However in order to check whether a string is uninitialised, use

```
if (node.name == nil)
```

or

```
if (!node.name)
```

For an explanation on the difference, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-to-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c).