# Why do we need many types of "null" in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null

I'm new to Objective-C & SO, so bear with me - I've been reading some questions on when to use nil, NULL, or Nil.

My question is: Why do we need so many types of "null"? Can't Xcode (or a similar IDE) interpret what "null" is necessary for the situation?

To clarify, I'm not looking for *when* to use each - this is clearly explained. For example, why can't Objective-C simply define NULL as *nothing*, and then just use context to figure out which *nothing* you needed. I'm quite positive the answer will either be for historical, or necessary purposes (with an example please), or both.

e.g.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
mutableDictionary[@"someKey"] = NULL;
```

... in this case, the compiler would understand you need a "null" object inserted, & simply add this behind the scenes so the dictionary would behave intuitively (& not just cause an error).

Comment: In Objective C, nil *is* NULL *is* (a form of) 0 ..

Comment: The answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c explain when to use - from a contractual/semantic point of view - the different forms and the rationale behind such choices.

Comment: It's for hysterical reasons.

Comment: Just a side-note: Messages can be sent to nil without crashing the program, but any messages sent to NULL will crash the program.

Comment: That's not correct, @ZaneHelton; `nil == NULL`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18562946/

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's not correct, NULL is actually a void pointer (void *) while nil is an id. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @ZaneHelton, semantically they are not the same, but they are identical in value and will function interchangeably. You will not cause a crash by sending a message to `NULL` because `nil` _is_ `(id)NULL`. Look at your objc.h, and then types.h

Comment: this has relatively nothing to do with my question, but I'd like to say thanks for all the quick attention & responses! despite the 0 vote count, the attention from experts makes me enticed to keep using this resource (appropriately) :)

Comment: I guess you're right @JoshCaswell. I've been constantly told that sending a message to NULL will crash your program but after try after try it won't crash!

Comment: Perhaps the people telling you that are Java programmers, @ZaneHelton?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Usually just in tutorials and whatnot; I'd always taken their word for it. Thanks for making find out for myself!

Comment: Kudos for checking it out on your own, @ZaneHelton.

Answer (score 1):

there is an [NSHipster Article](http://nshipster.com/nil/) covering the different types of null
Basically, NULL is the null value for C-pointers,
nil is the null value for Objective-C-objects,
Nil is the null value for Objective-C-classes and
[NSNull null] is an Objective-C-Object to represent null.