# Calling a function that takes a completion handler that I'm not going to use, do I use nil, NULL or something else?

Tags: objective-c, null, completionhandler

When calling a method that has a completion handler as one of it's arguments, if I don't plan on using it, what is an appropriate argument to use?
e.g.

```
 [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

There are lots of examples of the differences between NULL and nil, I was thinking NULL as I think completion handlers are more of a C++ thing and not specific to Objective-c, but I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Do I use NULL, nil or something else?

**EDIT:**
Sorry I should have been more clear, I understand that nil and NULL are equivalent and it's convention to use nil for objects and NULL for pointers. I was asking more about which one I use for a completion handler.

Comment: They are equivalent, but by convention, `nil` is used for objects, `Nil` is used for class objects, and `NULL` is generally used for all other pointer types (including out pointers to objects, like `NSError **`.

Comment: Apple's own documentation guides shows `nil` for block pointers such as completion handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode has a "Jump to Definition" feature that can be used to answer this question.

Starting with `nil` takes us to MacTypes.h

```
#define nil __DARWIN_NULL
```

Following `__DARWIN_NULL` to _types.h we have

```
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
```

And starting from `NULL` takes us to stddef.h

```
#define NULL ((void*)0)
```

So `nil` and `NULL` are the same thing. By convention, `nil` is used for objects, and `NULL` is used for other pointer types.

The completion handler takes a `block` as an argument, and [a `block` is an Objective-C object](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8) so by convention, `nil` should be used when the completion block is not needed.

Comment: So I guess my next question would be in this case, is a completion handler (a block) a pointer? I realise it is just convention and won't effect what happens.

Comment: @mdb29 I fixed up the answer to better match the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses NULL in at least some of their Objective-C docs.  Here's [an example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration).

For a general discussion of nil vs NULL in Objective-C, see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564410/when-should-i-use-nil-and-null-in-objective-c/).

I've just used NULL in Obj-C to match Apple's docs.  In Swift, use nil.