# C array of Objective C objects

Tags: objective-c, c, malloc

I'm trying to create a C array of objective C NSStrings using malloc.  I'm not doing it right, but I don't think I'm far off.  Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
Let's say we want 5 strings in our array for the sake of argument.

Interface:

```
@interface someObject : NSObject {
    NSString **ourArray;
}
@property () NSString **ourArray;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation someObject
@synthesize ourArray;

-(id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self->ourArray = malloc(5 * sizeof(NSString *));
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)getStringAtPos3 {
    if(self.ourArray[3] == nil) {
        self.ourArray[3] = @"a string";
    }
    return self.ourArray[3];
}
@end
```

When I set a breakpoint in getStringAtPos3 it doesn't see the array element as nil so it never goes into the if statement.

Comment: There is no need to **ever** use `self->`.  It'll give old hat ObjC developers hives if you do.

Comment: Note also that a C array of pointers to Objective-C objects is an exceedingly atypical pattern.   Just use an `NSArray` or `NSPointerArray` instead.

Comment: What's bad about using `self->`?  Also I'm developing for iOS which doesn't have `NSPointerArray`, but I want an array of a dynamic size which can have null entries.  Presumably C arrays are faster too, although it wouldn't make much difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem - I should have been using calloc, not malloc.  While malloc simply allocates the memory, calloc

> contiguously allocates enough space for count objects that are size bytes of memory each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The allocated memory is filled with bytes of value zero.

This means you get an array of nil objects essentially as in objective c 0x0 is the nil object.

Comment: No, that's not what it means. Confusingly perhaps, a null pointer is not guaranteed to be all-zeroes, which is what `calloc` gives you. (It is on i386, but never rely on it.) Explicitly set all elements to null and add the `sizeof` as @chrisaycock suggests.

Comment: Mm, I don't think so, larsmans.  C99 section 6.3.2.3, "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void \*, is called a null pointer constant."  and "The macro NULL is defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.17.".  7.17 specifies NULL as a macro "which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant".  So, NULL could be 0 or (void\*)0 in different implementations, but not 1.

Comment: @Ken Both of those are constant expressions, though. @larsmans is correct that there is no guarantee that `NULL` will be represented internally with all zero bits. That said, it is on iOS/OS X, and rather safe to depend upon for those systems.

Comment: 0x0 is the nil object though, so surely if calloc allocates the pointer as a set of zeros, then it will be the nil object?  Using calloc works on i386 and arm anyway.

Comment: +1 for Justin: this rule is only true in constant expressions of pointer type, while `calloc` writes zeroes of byte type. The 0 in that case is translated by the compiler to whatever is the proper null pointer for the current platform. Relying on null being all-zeroes is non-portable and may break the application if it moves to a different platform.

Comment: However, this code is not designed to be portable - it's an array of ObjC objects.  So surely iterating through the whole array and setting nil just wastes time?

Comment: @Nick: Why on earth would you want to `calloc` this array and handle it in an intentionally non-portable way, when Objective-C gives you easier-to-use, portable tools to begin with? AFAICT, you're abusing C by discarding it's portability features and abusing ObjC by unnecessarily (?) dropping down to the level of C. Sorry if this sounds harsh, I just can't figure out why you'd want to do this in the first place.

Comment: From my comment on the original question: I'm developing for iOS which doesn't have NSPointerArray, but I want an array of a dynamic size which can have null entries. Presumably C arrays are faster too, although it wouldn't make much difference in this case.  If nothing else, it's increasing my understanding on this stuff.

Comment: Ah, that seems a valid reason. I don't think C arrays are any faster though, although I have no experience in ObjC. I can tell you that in C++, the "native" solution is often as fast as C.

Comment: I think they would be faster as using NSArrays involve objective c message sends which are quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc`ing an array of pointers is done as follows:

```
self->ourArray = malloc(5 * sizeof(NSString *));
if (self->ourArray == NULL)
    /* handle error */
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    self->ourArray[i] = nil;
```

`malloc` doesn't make guarantees about the contents of the returned buffer, so set everything to `nil` explicitly. `calloc` won't help you here, as a zero pattern and `nil`/`NULL` aren't the same thing.

**Edit**: even though zero and null may be the same on i386 and arm, they are not the same conceptually, just like [`NULL` and `nil` are strictly not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c). Preferably, define something like

```
void *allocStringPtrs(size_t n)
{
    void *p = malloc(sizeof(NSString *));
    if (p == NULL)
        // throw an exception
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        p[i] = nil;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Is it best to use malloc or calloc then?  calloc does return all nil objects though.

Comment: `calloc` may return all `nil`-objects *on your platform*, but does not guarantee this; it's a coincidence. It is good style not to rely on such low-level platform features. It's even better to use a native Objective C solution like `NSArray` and stay clear of C interfaces such as `malloc`. If you must use these interfaces, use `malloc` for pointer arrays and set the elements explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is this:

```
self->ourArray = malloc(5 * sizeof(NSString *));  // notice the sizeof()
```

Comment: Yes, I just typed the example up here and missed that, thanks.