# Pass object in wcf problem?

Tags: iphone, wcf

I have to implement WCF web service in iPhone. But problem is that when i try to pass an object then it send me null value and when i post nil value for object then its give me response

```
SDZAuthService* service = [SDZAuthService service];
    service.logging = YES;
     service.username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"USERID"];
    service.password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PASSWORD"];


    // Returns SDZLoginUserResult*. 
    //[service LoginFBUser:self action:@selector(LoginFBUserHandler:) fbUserId: @"" ctx: [[SDZServiceContext alloc] init]];

    SDZServiceContext *object=[[SDZServiceContext alloc]init];

    object.CallerUserId = 1;
    object.CallerUserHostAddress = @"127.0.0.1";
    object.ContextData = nil;
    // Returns SDZLoginUserResult*. 
    [service LoginUser:self action:@selector(LoginUserHandler:) userName:service.username password:service.password ctx:object];
```

If i pass nil value instead of passing object to ctx: then its send me reposne but for object it give me null value.

Thanks for your help
Avnish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may know that in Objective-C [nil is for reference objects and NULL is for non-object pointers (C references & such)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c). Sounds like the client code is not initializing the ctx after the service call is made. If you control the WCF service, you should [enable message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) to see what the service is receiving.