# NSString internals - how does length works?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, performance, cocoa

I've a question about NSString internals.
I want to check a string length and basically I wanted to know if a NSString knows its length / count each time / count & cache the result.

Should I store it's length and compute or call the length method each time ?

To test a string I can test against nil OR ask for it's length.

```
if (str != nil) {
  // compute
}

if ([str length]) {
  // compute
}
```

Which one is the fastest ?
Which one is the more memory efficient ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checking for `nil` ("no object") is most definitely *not* the same as sending the `length` message to the (NSString) object. Only one of the conditional checks is valid to test for an "empty" string. (An "empty" string is an object and, therefore, not `nil`.)

The bigger question is: does NSString store a length or is it sentinel-terminated (like a "normal c string")? NSString stores the length as an internal property so it, `length`, is as O(1) operation.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how CFStringGetLength works:

(from http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.43/CFString.c)

```
/* Returns length; use __CFStrLength2 if contents buffer pointer has already been computed.
*/
CF_INLINE CFIndex __CFStrLength(CFStringRef str) {
    if (__CFStrHasExplicitLength(str)) {
        if (__CFStrIsInline(str)) {
                return str->variants.inline1.length;
        } else {
                return str->variants.notInlineImmutable1.length;
        }
    } else {
        return (CFIndex)(*((uint8_t *)__CFStrContents(str)));
    }
}
```

So it should be O(1) for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

The two -- testing a NSString pointer for nil and testing the length of an NSString -- are not in any way equivalent.  An NSString object with a zero length can exist, and a pointer to it will not compare equal to nil.

To my knowledge (and I'd be quite surprised to discover I was wrong), the length of an NSString is stored within the object as an efficiently-referenced property.  Caching the length would generally be unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

NSString is immutable class, so the length stays the same all of the time.

Comment: Does an `NSMutableString` also store its length as an O(1) property?

Comment: I assume (because it much more efficient) but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Addendum: Testing against [string length] evaluates to 0/nil/NO in both cases (string being nil and string having zero length).

Comment: That reminds me: I've always wondered, coming from both a Java and a Smalltalk background, what nil is, exactly. Is it a special class (like in Smalltalk, where there are no primitives, and everything (!) is an object), or just a constant that amounts to int 0? I suppose due to the c roots, 0, nil, NULL, NO, false are all the same - 0?

Comment: `nil` is defined in [objc.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.3/runtime/objc.h) as `__DARWIN_NULL`, which is defined in <sys/_types.h> as `((void *)0)`.

Comment: @fzwo `nil` and `null` are special values that represent "no object". `nil` is the the sole inhabitant of the respective "none type": even with implementation detail leakage ("0/NULL"), it can be thought of as such. That is, `nil` is a value that can only mean one thing: "no object". [NULL vs nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) may be interesting as it shows that Objective-C really just is a layer on C/C++ ;-) [What I said above relies on the use of semantics.]