# iOS: How to Check if an "int" Value Equals to "nil"

Tags: ios, if-statement, int, null

I have an int value defined in one of my method:

**int value = [self someMethodThatGetsAnINT];**

Later on I have some "ifs" that check upon this value.

How to I express: **if (value == nil)**?

When I try do this intuitive code writing I get a warning saying:

**Semantic Issue: Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *')**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`nil` is just a `0` :) Try this :

```
if (0 == value)
```

However, why would you be testing `nil` against an int - something sounds funny here :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want a nil value returned, you should probably be using NSNumber as your return type instead of int. NSNumber is an class that wraps scalar values in objective-c. You can put an integer in it when you have a valid return value, or return nil when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

you can probably use `if (value == (int)nil)` but really a function that returns an int shouldn't return nil as nil is not an integer (although it may be represented similarly).

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) may help clear it up a little