# Does the automatic reference counting release an object if i set the pointer to nil?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Does the automatic reference counting release an object if I set the pointer to nil or assign the pointer to another object?

For example doing something like that:

```
//in .h file

@interface CustomView : UIView
{
   UIView *currentView;
}


// in .m file:

-(void)createView1
{
   currentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   [self addSubview:currentView];
}

-(void)createView2
{
   [currentView removeFromSuperview];

   // does the former view get released by arc
   // or does this leak?
   currentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   [self addSubview:currentView];
}
```

If this code leaks, how would I declare *currentView properly? Or how would I make ARC "release" the currentView? thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dangling pointers in objective c - does nil also release memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873253/dangling-pointers-in-objective-c-does-nil-also-release-memory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ARC you don't need to think about `release/retain`.

Since your variable will have been implicitly defined as `strong` there's no need to set it to `NULL` -  it'll be released before it's assigned to.

Personally though I prefer to declare properties:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *currentView;
```

Comment: I like your answer better (and +1, too)... while what I suggested in my answer seems like good coding style, I've been trying to find any reference in [Apple's ARC documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4) to prove one way or another.

Comment: `nil`. FYI - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c

Comment: thanks! i was pretty unsure about that.. but it really makes sense! ;)

Answer (score 3):

After doing `[currentView removeFromSuperview]`, you should call `currentView = nil` and ARC will do it's release magic. You can then reassign `currentView` with that new UIView there.