# Dangling pointers in objective c - does nil also release memory?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

What I understand is:

Memory leaks occur when memory has not been freed or "released"
Dangling pointers occur when the pointer is NOT set to nil AND the object is released.

my question is: Can setting the object to nil free the memory and clear the pointer reference?

i.e.

```
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] initWithCoolRims: YES];
myCar = nil;
//no mem leaks or dang pointers
```

or does the ARC do this:

```
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] initWithCoolRims: YES];
[myCar release];    
myCar = nil;
//no mem leaks or dang pointers
```

Thankyou

Comment: afaik, `myCar = nil;` does not cause memory to be released (ref count is unchanged), so in the first case you have a mem leak. In the second case, no mem leak, and by nil-lifying `myCar` you avoid dang ptrs (provided you check it the ptr is nil before using it...)

Comment: Is your question "does ARC do this" or "must I do this manually"? The two "no memory leaks" comments contradict each other.

Comment: @ShinTakezou Under ARC, setting `__strong` pointers to `nil` causes the pointed object to be `- release`d.

Comment: @H2CO3 interesting; I don't remember if `Car *myCar` is a strong or weak ptr, not being explicitly stated; I suppose the answer is the default is strong then

Comment: @ShinTakezou: Object pointers are strong references unless otherwise marked. If that weren't the case, ARC would be within its rights to deallocate the object before you even had a chance to use it.

Comment: it should've been "I didn't remember if...", H2CO3 clarified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under **ARC**

For your first example `myCar` will be set to `nil` and the newly created `Car` will get deallocated at some point. This is because `myCar` is the only thing that has a reference to your newly created `Car`.

If something else had a strong pointer to the newly created `Car` then this would simply `nil` out `myCar`'s reference and the other interested references would determine the lifetime of the `Car` instance

Under **Non-ARC**

People still do this?

Your first example would indeed be a memory leak - you have lost the only pointer to your new `Car` instance without decrementing the +1 reference from the `alloc`.

Comment: Important to note that this is true only under ARC.

Comment: @bbum always seem to take it for granted that people have moved on from non-ARC. Updated my answer to reinforce your comment.

Comment: Paul your edit clarified everything. thankyou so much!

Answer (score 1):

You do the first, ARC does the equivalent of the second. There are no dangling references, with or without the nil assignment, since ARC retained the referenced object (retain count 1) and when execution moves beyond the scope of the myCar definition, ARC will guarantee a release of myCar's referenced object, decrementing the reference count and deallocating the object memory if the resulting reference count is 0.