# ARC behavior on assigned local variable to an instance variable

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

### Question 1

Supposed I have this code:

```
MyClass * __strong foo = [MyClass new];
MyClass * __strong bar = foo;
// foo = nil; // by ARC?
```

In reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873253/dangling-pointers-in-objective-c-does-nil-also-release-memory/20873312#20873312), does `ARC` automatically nil out `foo` on line 3 since `bar` already acquired the reference?

### Question 2

```
//ECGService.m
@property (strong) MuttableArray *rriData;

(MuttableArray *)getRriData {
    return _rriData;
}

//AlgorithmTest.m
// according to Apple docs, local variable are marked __strong by default
MuttableArray *rriData = [self.ecgService getRriData];
for(NSNumber *rri in rriData) {
    // use rri!
}
// rriData = nil;
```

Should I nil out the local variable `rriData` after using it?

And, does the `__strong` attribute must only be applied to only one instance of an object?

Comment: In question 1, are those local variables, instance variables, or global variables?

Comment: @robmayoff local variables in function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1.

In principle, ARC doesn't “nil out” `foo` until it goes out of scope. When it goes out of scope, ARC releases its reference. It doesn't have to actually set `foo` to nil, but the effect is exactly as if ARC does set it to nil.

In practice, ARC is usually allowed to release the reference held by `foo` immediately after the last use of the `foo` variable, which may be long before it goes out of scope. In your example, if the only place where you use `foo` in the function is in the assignment to `bar`, then ARC is allowed to release `foo`'s reference immediately after that assignment. Note that generally there's no way for you to know about this early release because you don't use `foo` again! Note also that `bar` will still reference the object unless `bar` is also not used later in the function.

There are some special attributes that can prevent ARC from performing this early release, called `objc_precise_lifetime` and `objc_returns_inner_pointer` but usually applied through the macros `NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE` and `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER`. These are advanced features that you probably won't have to worry about any time soon, but if you want to see some examples of `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER`, take a look at `NSString.h`.

### Answer 2.

You don't need to “nil out” `rriData`. ARC will release its reference when it goes out of scope (or sooner—see answer 1).

You don't need to say `__strong` usually, because it's the default, and it's what you want usually. It is normal to have multiple strong references to an object. You use `__weak` explicitly when you need to prevent a retain cycle. There are many explanations of retain cycles on the web and on stack overflow, so if you need to learn about them, please visit your favorite search engine.

Comment: You should replace *out of scope* with *out of extent*. Usually scope and extent are congruent, but this is not necessarily that way (i. e.local variables with `static` storage class) and if there is a difference, extent what decides.

Answer (score 1):

> In reference to this answer, does ARC automatically nil out foo on line 3 since bar already acquired the reference?

No. ARC stands for Automatic Reference *Counting*. Obviously counting does not stop with 1.

It is the strength of ARC that every reference is handled independently of other references. A strong `foo` retains the referred object as long as it points to. It does not matter, whether other reference variables points to the same object. Track every reference isolated.

There is only one case that let ARC change the value of a reference variable: If it is marked with `weak` and there is no other strong reference to the object. This is the intended behavior.

As a result of optimization it is possible that retains and releases are omitted or different local variables in source code are put together. This is transparent for you.

> Should I nil out the local variable rriData after using it?

You should not care about this. A strong reference variable automatically retains an object, whose reference is stored in the reference variable. And it automatically releases the object, if it does not point any longer to it. This includes releases on

- a new value is assigned to the reference variable
- `nil` is assigned to the reference variable
- the reference variable loses it extent (lifetime).

Because of the last fact, there will be an automatically generated release, when `rriData` loses it extent. There is no reason to nil it out in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. No, you simply end up with two references to the MyClass instance. Nothing gets nilled out.

Question 2. No, you don't need to nil out anything. ARC manages memory for you. That's the point. You also never need to say `__strong`. It is the default.