# Is it okay to pass in NULL to a block parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

iOS does not scream at me when I pass in `NULL` or `nil` to the completion block in `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` but does that mean it's okay? Or is it better to open an empty `^{ }`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is okay as long as you can trust that the code to which you are passing the `nil` won't try to call it as a block.

A quick demonstration:

```
typedef void (^GenericBlock)(void);

void useThisBlock(GenericBlock block){
    block();
}

useThisBlock(^{NSLog(@"All okay.");});
useThisBlock(nil);    // Compiles but crashes
```

The inner code must check the block first: `if( block ) block();`

In the case of UIKit code, you should be fine.

Comment: "*In the case of UIKit code, you should be fine.*" Citations needed?

Comment: @Manav: You're not wrong -- there's no way to verify (except that it doesn't crash).

Answer (score 6):

Passing `nil` is fine, and in my opinion yields cleaner-reading code.

If you don't want to use a completion block, for this case you can also use the `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` method.

Comment: Thanks, I know there is a method without animation block. My question is more about block itself. So why `nil`, not `NULL`?

Comment: `nil` and `NULL` are equivalent. By convention, Objective-C typically uses `nil` where `NULL` is used in C.

Comment: that's not exactly true in ARC. `nil` means object and must be used where `id` is expected, whereas `NULL` means a non-object non valid pointer and must be used where `(void *)` is expected. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) question for further information.