# Objective-C Possible shorter "if " notation?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Is there a way to shorten this if statement ?

```
if(objectA != objectD && objectB != objectD && objectC != objectD)
```

something like this pseudo code:

```
if(objectA && objectB && objectC != objectD)
```

EDIT:

and what if i only want to check if it is not NULL? Something like:

```
if(objectA != NULL && objectB != NULL && objectC != NULL)
```

EDIT 2 (sorry):

and what if i only want to check if it is not NSNull?

```
if(objectA != [NSNull null] && objectB != [NSNull null] && objectC != [NSNull null])
```

Comment: Not really.  No common language, to my knowledge, contains such a construct (though there are many times when something of that ilk would be handy).  I suspect that one of the problems is coming up with a non-ambiguous notation that's general enough to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL`, `nil` and `0` are [technically the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c):

From [MacTypes.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacTypes.h)

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL    __DARWIN_NULL
#endif /* ! NULL */
#ifndef nil
    #define nil NULL
#endif /* ! nil */
```

And you can verify that `NULL` is some variation of `0` by fishing through the header files like [`stddef.h`](http://www.vsm.com.au/ftp/kits/gcc-for-alpha/include/STDDEF.H).

So to ensure they all exist, to just test for `NULL`, or more accurately, since these are objects, `nil`:

```
if (objectA && objectB && objectC) ...
```

But, IMO, you shouldn't do this unless you need to act on the fact that they're `nil`. Since `nil` accepts messages, it can often be better to structure your code so that `nil` can be a valid receiver. That is, if nothing happens when sending messages to these `nil` objects, it doesn't cause any problems. In other words, consider not using `nil` as an error case but rather return a `*NSError` from APIs that can fail.

With respect to **the NSNull issue specifically**, I wrote an *example* of [how to simplify code using variadic functions](https://gist.github.com/nicerobot/1550857#file-vac-m). It'll allow you to write:

```
if (isNSNull(objectA, objectB, objectC, objectD, nil)) ...
```

to test whether all the objects == `[NSNull null]`. You can also use a similar technique to test if they are all the same object:

```
if (isEqualTo(objectD, objectA, objectB, objectC, nil)) ...
```

will return `YES` if A, B, and C are all `==` to D.

The crux of the example is:

```
// This is just a simple object equality comparator.
static NSComparator compareeq = ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
  if (obj1 == obj2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
  }
  return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
};

// This'll execute the above comparator to compare eq to each object in args
NSComparisonResult comparatorV(NSComparator compare, NSObject *eq, va_list args) {
  NSComparisonResult result;
  NSObject *value;
  do {
    if (value = va_arg(args, NSObject*)) {
      result = compare(eq,value);
    }
  } while (value && result == NSOrderedSame);
  return (!value?NSOrderedDescending:NSOrderedSame);
}

// This just test if each object passed is == [NSNull null].
BOOL isNSNull(NSObject *o, ...) {
  NSNull *n = [NSNull null];
  if (NSOrderedSame != compareeq(n,o)) return NO;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, o);
  BOOL result = (NSOrderedSame != comparatorV(compareeq,n,args));
  va_end(args);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: He is not checking for a null value, he is checking for the `NSNull` singleton object, which will never be `0`.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert He asks: "and what if i only want to check if it it not NULL"? Regardless of his coded example, and since he also asks "Something like?" it's assumed he doesn't know the correct technique, so i answered his question and it's how i would do it and what i think is generally the best approach.

Comment: Yeah well, this is another example why it is important to give a question as much details as possible (which i didn't) cause indeed i wanted to check for the NSNULL object since the NSJSONSerialization object creates those for me..

Comment: @Tieme I've edited my answer to include a technique to simplify such tedious code.

Comment: @nicerobot Haha nice one, you get extra credits for the hard work. Maybe it is a good idea to include a small snippet of your script in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if three objects (a, b, and c) are equal to object D, you may be able to do the following:

```
if (objectA == objectB == objectC == objectD) {
    // .. your code here ..
}
```