# ARC, bridged cast and GHUnit

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, gh-unit

I'm followinng tutorial from http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/docs/appledoc_include/guide_testing.html. The problem is that my project uses ARC and GHUnit doesn't. I managed previous errors, but now i should do bridged cast, that i've never used, and i'm lost.

```
NSString *string1 = @"a string";
GHAssertNotNULL(string1, nil); //error here
```

Error description: Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'const void *' requires a bridged cast.

Any help welcome :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are comparing an NSString, you should use the GHAssertNotNil check.  See [NULL vs nil in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c) for more info.

So your example should read:

```
NSString *string1 = @"a string";
GHAssertNotNil(string1, nil);
```

I've also noticed in my ARC projects using GHUnit that the GHUnit main.m file needs the

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

linker flag as was suggested previously.

Comment: Good catch. The current documentation just uses GHAssertNotNull instead of GHAssertNotNil, which causes issues with ARC code.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude only GHUnit files from automatics referencing(ARC) from your project by going into 
Build Phase -> Compile Sources

and then double click on the files from GHUnit, a box will appear, paste following into it

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

This will exclude the files from GHUnit from automatics referencing(ARC).

Comment: Thats a good idea until GHUnit don't implement ARC. However i still wish to know how to do these bridges, as far trying to get this info from some ARC-references.