# Delegate not working when converting point from superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been stuck with an issues for a couple of days and I think it's time to ask for help.

I have an UIView class "BonusObjects" which is set as delegate to ViewController.

I add some UIImageViews in this class, start moving them towards the edge of the screen with NSTimer and try to see if they intersect with an UIImageView from ViewController.m. I'm getting the coords of the target object as int and check if the X and Y of the images from BonusObjects are anywhere near the target.

Since the images from BonusObject have X=0, I have to convert their coords from the superview. Like that:

```
CGPoint newPoint = [[self superview]convertPoint:internal.center 
                                        fromView:[internal superview]];

bonusX= newPoint.x;
```

**Here is the actual question**: Why the delegate doesn't work in this `if` statement:

```
if (padX < bonusX && bonusX < padX+40 && padY <= internal.frame.origin.y) {

    [[self delegate] bonusEffect:internal.tag];

    [internal removeFromSuperview];
    internal=NULL;
}
```

But it works if I put it out of the if, or change bonusX to some random value that isn't taken from the superview.

Everything else in that if works fine - it removes the image, and displays the correct .tag value.

I can provide more code if needed.

**EDIT**: The delegate is `(null)` in that `if`, but outside of it it is `<ViewController: 0xc03e600>`.

**EDIT2**: Here is how I set the delegate:

in BonusObjects.h

```
@protocol BonusDelegate

-(void)bonusEffect:(int)effect;

@end


@interface BonusObjects : UIView <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    id <BonusDelegate> delegate;
     } @property (nonatomic)  id <BonusDelegate> delegate;
```

in ViewController.h:

```
#import "BonusObjects.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <BonusDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate> {


     BonusObject *bonusView;
       }
```

And in ViewController.m:

```
 bonusView = [[BonusObjects alloc] init];
 [bonusView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Can you add that additional code into your question.

Comment: This isn't the cause, but ` internal=NULL` is better as `internal = nil`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c

Comment: @nihilvex, don't use the Quote button to format code.  Use the Code button `{}` instead.

Comment: So are you saying, that everything works fine, only the `if` condition is never `true`?

Comment: No, the if condition is true when they intersect, and everything in it works fine except for the delegate. The delegate is (null) inside that if, but working outside of it.

Comment: IF you comment out the if() line and closing brace of the if-block, but leave all else as is,does it still get set to null? If so stick a breakpoint somewhere above it and watch the delegate, you should see exactly where this is happening.

Comment: I guess the fact that I'm using ARC causes that issue.. have to find a way to retain the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. In ViewController.m where I create the BonusObject I had to set the delegate for that object to self.

```
BonusObjects *newObj = [[BonusObjects alloc] initWithFrame:objRect];
        newObj.delegate=self;
        [self.view addSubview:newObj];
```

I was setting the `delegate` of the view to `self`, but not for the object itself.
Works like a charm now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`(padX < bonusX && bonusX < padX)` will always fail

Comment: haha true, I deleted a value when posting it. The actual code is padX < bonusX && bonusX < padX+40