# Checking to see if a structure exists? [C]

Tags: objective-c, c, hash, structure

Background: I created a Hashtable in a file called hash_table.c. Here is part of what my header file hash_table.h contains:

```
/* hash_table.h */
#ifndef HASH_TABLE_H
#define HASH_TABLE_H

enum {BUCKET_COUNT = 1024};

struct Node {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Table {
    struct Node *array[BUCKET_COUNT];
};

struct Table *TableCreate(void);   //creates the table
....
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I want to initiate the Hashtable in a different C file called fdata.c. I don't know what the best way to do this is but here is what I was thinking:

```
#include "hash_table.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Table *t;  //initiate the variable

void testFunc()
{
    if(Hashtable does not exist) {  //How do I accomplish this? Is it possible?
        t = TableCreate(); //create the table
    else{
        continue...
    ....
```

Obviously, if there is a better way to initiate this table I am all ears. (This is my first time using structures with C)

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global pointer will be initialized to `nil` on app startup. You can compare against `nil` and then call `TableCreate`.

Alternatively, you can just create the table at startup. (e.g. from `main`, or if you're actually writing Objective C, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or something along those lines.)

Comment: What's the difference between using NULL and nil because nil gives me an error while NULL seems to be working.

Comment: There's no big difference in meaning. Objective C uses nil, regular C uses NULL. They both mean zero.

Comment: `nil` is for objects, `NULL` for non-objects! See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557582/null-vs-nil-in-objective-c)